# Encoding for a .tex file created under Mac and opened under Windows

Tags: texmaker, windows, input-encodings, mac

When I open a .tex file with Texmaker under Win8.1, that was created on a Mac using TexShop, I get the following error:

> It seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8)

Different choices for an encoding option are then proposed. I select "macintosh", and the file opens correctly.

However, after saving it, when I open it again, the same error pops up again.

I guess I have to open the file with "macintosh" but save it with another encoding. I did not find a way to do so.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should be using UTF-8 in TeXShop, too. (I thought this was default but maybe not.)

Comment: @cfr The default encoding of TeXShop is Mac OS Roman (corresponding to the `applemac` option of the `inputenc` package).

Comment: @fpast Really? I wonder why. In any case, the OP should certainly change it, if so.

Comment: @cfr I correct myself: the default encoding of TeXShop was indeed Mac OS Roman… until version 3.15. Since this version the default has been changed to Iso Latin 9. Still a 8-bit encoding, essentially for backward compatibility with old 8bits-encoded TeX files, but less specific than Mac OS Roman.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that Texmaker proposes a simple way of doing it. There is a Unicode converter in the "Tools" toolbar.

There, one selects the .tex file to open and specifies the original encoding. The file is then automatically converted!